# React Native AsyncStorage or Context

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context, asyncstorage

I'm currently building an app that has a very small amount of data that needs to be shared with all components. For example, the unique user id, subscription information, etc.

I'm currently storing all this information in `AsyncStorage` and pulling this information from each component. Is this an acceptable way to store this information?

All my components are class components. Should I continue to use `AsyncStorage` this way? Should I use Context providers?

Wrapping all components in context will be a good amount of work.  I'd rather not convert class components into functional components, but that would make context a bit easier with `useContext`. I'm fairly new to react native just looking for best solution before I continue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Will the values ever change? if so, async storage isn't going to notify your components about that, so they won't rerender.

Comment: no, these values are set after login and wont change unless logged out and back in.

Answer (score 1):

I think using context will be better solution.
You can also use state management like MobX or Redux.

You should use the async storage only if you need to save data locally for later use.
For example, if you want to save user token so he won't have to login each time he enter the app.
And if you do so, At app launch read values from storage to context / state.

One more small thing.. If you do save any sensitive data to async storage be aware that async storage isn't a secure storage.